# CreateObject equivalent in C/C++? (COM Interop)

Tags: c++, c, com, interop

What would the equivalent in C/C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the [CoCreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615(VS.85).aspx) function.

> It is convenient to use
>   CoCreateInstance when you need to
>   create only a single instance of an
>   object on the local machine. If you
>   are creating an instance on remote
>   computer, call CoCreateInstanceEx.
>   When you are creating multiple
>   instances, it is more efficient to
>   obtain a pointer to the class object's
>   IClassFactory interface and use its
>   methods as needed. In the latter case,
>   you should use the CoGetClassObject
>   function.

You'll need to #include <Objbase.h> and you'll need to link to ole32.lib

Answer (score 6):

Just two calls.  You need CLSIDFromProgID() to map the argument you normally pass to CreateObject to a CLSID.  Which you can then use in CoCreateInstance().

Answer (score 5):

Do not forget to call CoInitializeEx or CoInitialize before CoCreateInstance